# Rails locking a 'completed' 'todo'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a Todo model with `title:string, description:text` and `completed:boolean` and two self references: children & parents joined by a todos_todos table (parent_id, child_id).

I want to prevent a Todo with `completed == true` from being edited unless the user passes `params[:completed] = false`. I also want to prevent children from being added to the todo if it's completed.

I know I can do this easily in the controller with this:

```
def update 
    ...
    @todo.find(params[:id])
    if params[:completed] == false 
        if @todo.completed == true 
            render :edit
            ...
end
```

...but I'm not sure that's the correct way to do this. I feel like I should use a validation in my model for this, except I can't figure out a way compare to user's input with existing data in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `authorization` (preferably with [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)):

```
#Gemfile
gem "cancancan"

#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    cannot :manage, Todo, completed: true
  end
end

#app/controllers/todos_controller.rb
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  laod_and_authorize_resource
end
```

This will prevent any interactivity with the aforementioned records unless you explicitly define it in the `Ability` class (maybe you have `admin` users who can do things etc).

Comment: Ah. I was hoping to avoid adding user authorization until I'd finished adding all the Todo features. I guess I'll have to go with this. Thanks.


edit: I'll accept your answer in a bit. I'm still holding out hope that there's a way to do this in the Todo model


edit 2: Why cancancan and not rolify?

Comment: I'll need to add authorization later on anyway, so I might as well get it done now.

Comment: Authorization is great if you have users - putting it in now is just a way to get the functionality in place for the future

Comment: I have users and I _do_ intend on them having roles. I knew I'd end up installing cancan at some point, I just didn't think I'd need it for this.

Comment: CanCanCan & Pundit are the best authorization gems out there. I believe Rolify is just to set roles for a user (not permissions)

Answer (score 1):

You *should* validate it, but the most important thing is to prevent the user from being able to make the unwanted change in the first place.  That means that these limitations are implemented in **the interface**.  For example, when you render out the todo, you can render either the locked or unlocked version (which allows more stuff).  They can update the "locked" status, which will reload the page (or div if you do it via ajax) and then they'll see the other version.

This is all very broad and general, but so is your question.

Comment: Yeah, I'll add all the interface hints, but I would like the model to validate that the existing todo is not completed before updating it with the user's input.